# Unable to run cgi script

Tags: apache2, cgi, backuppc

I've installed backuppc on a fresh Xubuntu. Everything went fine except that when I try to access the web interface, instead of running the CGI script I'm prompted to download a bin file.

I'm no apache2 expert but backuppc.conf file looks fine to me:

```
Alias /backuppc /usr/share/backuppc/cgi-bin/

<Directory /usr/share/backuppc/cgi-bin/>
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all

    Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi

    AuthUserFile /etc/backuppc/htpasswd
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "BackupPC admin"
    require valid-user

</Directory>
```

I already enabled cgi module (`a2enmod cgi`). Also I've checked apache2 error.log and didn't find any.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you already enabled cgi module, are you sure you restarted apache2?

Comment: @Khaled Yes I even restarted the server.